# how can we get dataset with generic handler or jquery from Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Like for a single value i easily work, or also true false condition. 
like getting a single value from database

```
                    string i = "";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SelectPass";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        i = reader["Password"].ToString();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                    if (i == "")
                    { context.Response.Write("False"); }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.Write(i);
                    }
```

and in client side easily showing the value in one variable.

```
 function abc()
{   
    $.get('\HandlerResetPass.ashx?id=' + $('#txtUserId').val()+'&lbl='+ $('#lblPasswo').val(), callback);
    function callback(data)
    {

    if (data == "False")
    {
    alert('ID doesn\'t exist try again..!')
    return false;
    }
    else 
    {
    $('#tblPassWord').show();
    $('#tblprofile').hide();
    role = data;
    }
    }
}
```

But how working with A dataset.

Comment: I just want to know if i get the whole profile against this ID then how to context.Response.Write(datatable); How?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can return data set from handler by useing that king of work.

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string connect = (@"Connection string");

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn))
            {
                string i = "";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "Selecttest";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_ID", context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                string ans = "";
                ans = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["name"])+",";
                ans += Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["age"]);
                context.Response.Write(ans);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or in client side we get these two values by this method.

```
 function abc()
{
$.get('\Handler1.ashx?id=' + $('#txtID').val(), callback);
 function callback(data)
 {

    var arr = data.split(',');  
    $("#name").html(arr[0]);   
    $("#age").html(arr[1]);  
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What exactly your HandlerResetPass is returning? if is a list of object you should define a class with the structure of your data, serialize json for example, the in your client side, jquery can go through your list ,and process your data.

Comment: I want to know how to response fro a dataset, like for C# we can Just write  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                conn.Close();
                return ds; but how for jquree

Comment: you can't return ds to jquery, you should send back a list, array of your data. for example if you'd like to read Name {FirstName, LastName}, you should make a class of Name with 2 string fields, then read your dataset or datareaader to make a list of Name, and serialize it. then you return to ajax call. Read the documentation about $.ajax with .net to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can return JSON and then parse it to an object using jQuery's [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

For instance,

```
// data = '{"field1": "value1", "field2": false}'
function callback(data) {
  dataObj = $.parseJSON(data)
  if(dataObj["field2"] == false) {
    // do something
  }
  else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my having some bit of code for getting dataset values.

For that first you have to create class object for that require table data.
Like below

```
Class MyData
  Public ID As Integer
  Public Name As String
  Public ContactNo As String
End Class
```

Now you need to define Structure for BasicOuputObject. object of this BasicOuputObject 
is sent over from server side to client.

```
Public Structure BasicOuputObject
     Dim status As String
     Dim errorMessage As String
     Dim strMessage As String
     Dim obj As Object
End Structure
```

Now you have to use below function for getting datatable.

```
Public Sub GetMyData()
    Dim objOutput As New BasicOuputObject
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim lstMyData As New List(Of MyData)
    Dim objMyData As MyData
    Dim objConn As New SqlConnection("Pass Connection String")
    objCommand.CommandText = "select ID ,Name ,ContactNo from Customers"
    objCommand.Connection = objConn

    objConn.Open()
    Dim m_rdrReader As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
    If m_rdrReader.HasRows Then
        While m_rdrReader.Read()
            objMyData = New MyData
            objMyData.ID = m_rdrReader(0)
            objMyData.Name = m_rdrReader(1)
            objMyData.ContactNo = m_rdrReader(2)
            lstMyData.Add(objMyData)
        End While
    End If
    m_rdrReader.Close()
    m_objConn.Close()

    objOutput.errorMessage = ""
    objOutput.obj = lstMyData
    objOutput.strMessage = "success"

    Dim objSerialiser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(objSerialiser.Serialize(objOutput))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

End Sub
End Class
```

Now modify javascript as below. use can use any machnism for calling above function 
from the handler.

```
function abc() {
    $.get('\HandlerResetPass.ashx?id=' + $('#txtUserId').val() + '&lbl=' +     $('#lblPasswo').val(), callback);
    function callback(data) {

        if (data.status == "success") {

            for (var row, i = 0; row = data.obj[i]; i++) {
                //Create the row strings using the CreateAddModelRowString function
                // Process row var for as per usage.
            }

        }
        else {

            alert('ID doesn\'t exist try again..!')
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. happy coding....